# Not able to read JSON data in perl

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, perl

I am trying to pass JSON data using Ajax and Jquery to a Perl script. In Perl script, trying to read the data back. But i am not able to read the data in Perl.

Can please someone help me out, is there anything wrong/missing. Code for both HTML and PERL is given below. Ajax call neither printing success alert nor error alert.

**This is HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"     </script>
<script src="json.js" </script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#get").click(function(){

var data = {
    "name": "Bob",
    "sex": "Male",
    "address": {
            "city": "San Jose",
            "state": "California"
    },
    "friends":
            [
                    {
                            "name": "Alice",
                            "age": "20"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "Laura",
                            "age": "23"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "Daniel",
                            "age": "30"
                    }
            ]
};



alert (data);
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    alert (dataString);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cgi-bin/test3.pl',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
                alert("data");

            },

   error: function()
    {
        alert ("something wrong");
    }
        });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <button id="get">save</button>

</body>
</html>
```

** This is My perl File **

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use DBI;
use JSON;

#print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $ddata = decode_json($cgi->param('dataString'));

my $value =  $ddata->{'address'}{'city'} ;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:test','root','') or die "Connection Error:     $DBI::errstr\n";
my $sql = "insert into samples values (NULL, '$value')";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute  or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You pass a string, not a data structure. Your CGI script returns no response. Try fixing these two problems.

Comment: You mean to say i need not to use JSON.stringify(...) in HTML file

Comment: Get Firebug for Firefox, check your ajax url/requests/responses. If there are no responses check also your web server logs.

Comment: In addition to any other answers here, your line:

```perl
my $sql = "insert into samples values (NULL, '$value')";
```

is an injection attack waiting to happen.  See http://www.bobby-tables.com/ for more information.  You should use placeholders to assist you in sanitizing your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS side code doesn't POST a query parameter `dataString`, but POSTs have serialization in request body instead. You should change either Perl or JS side to agree on where they want this data to be (i.e. both in body or both in named parameter).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cgi-bin/test3.pl',
    data: { dataStr: dataString},
    success: function(){
            alert("data");

  },
```

PERL:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
...
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $ddata = decode_json($cgi->param('dataStr'));
....
```